# How to access elements in the report using java code

Tags: java, pentaho

How can I access each element in the `.prpt` file using Java? I need to retrieve e.g. a text field element and populate it with data.

I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String reportPath = "file:/home/username/reports/example_table.prpt";
    try {
        ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();
        ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
        resourceManager.registerDefaults();

        Resource resource = resourceManager.createDirectly(new URL(
                reportPath), MasterReport.class);
        MasterReport report = (MasterReport) resource.getResource();
        for(int i=0;i<report.getElementCount();i++){
        System.out.println("element :"+report.getElement(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Element count :" + report.getElementCount());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The `index` variable is the element count obtained from `report.getElementCount();`

The output is:

> PageHeader={name="", size='', layout=null}
>       ReportHeader=(name="", size='', layout=null}
>       DefaultGroup={Name='', fields=[]}

The output does not show any of the elements like text fields present in the `.prpt` file. Will Gorman's book does not have any example about this.

Below is the content of report-definition.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data-definition xmlns="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/classic/bundle/data/1.0">
<parameter-definition>
<list-parameter name="id" allow-multi-selection="false" strict-values="true" mandatory="true" type="java.lang.String" query="param_id_query" key-column="id" value-column="id">
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="role">user</attribute>
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="parameter-render-type">list</attribute>
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="re-evaluate-on-failed-values">false</attribute>
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="autofill-selection">false</attribute>
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="label">id</attribute>
  <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="hidden">false</attribute>
</list-parameter>
</parameter-definition>
</data-definition>
```

The report contains 2 text fields which I am trying to access from java and fill data using a query.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Are you using the [Pentaho Reporting Tool](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/reporting/)?

Comment: I use pentaho classic core 3.6.1-GA

Comment: The prpt was created using PRD 5.4.0.1

Comment: @WackyPundit can you add a small same of the report file? Is it `XML` or some other format?

Comment: @Verhagen I have added contents of report definition file

Comment: Can you share the Java code block, a little more then the two lines above?

Comment: @Verhagen Added java code

Comment: __Q:__ Why using http://maven-repository.com/artifact/pentaho-reporting-engine/pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core/3.6.1-GA for reading files which are created with 5.4.0.1

Comment: __Q:__ Where is version 5.4.0.1 found as Maven repository jar? Any url? artifact-id / group-id ?

Comment: @Verhagen Thanks.Changed the version of pentaho jars to 5.4.0.1 and used AbstractStructureVisitor as suggested by user4637357.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho reports are a tree-like hierarchical structure with MasterReport as the root element. getElement(i) gets just immediate child of the parent element. So, you may need to traverse through all elements recursively. However, there should be a `org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.util.AbstractStructureVisitor` class, which visits all elements in the report. You can extend it and put your logic into `inspectElement(final ReportElement element)`, method which is called for each visited element.
[Link for source code of the class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho/pentaho-reporting-engine/pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core/3.9.0-GA/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/core/util/AbstractStructureVisitor.java#AbstractStructureVisitor).
Then you may call it's `inspect(report)` method to do all the job. But I am not sure, if this class exists in 3.6 version.